# Can a Trailing Stop Limit order extend the upside?

Tags: stocks, limit-order, stop-order, thinkorswim

I'm looking to place a trailing stop on a stock **IF AND ONLY IF** the stock reaches a certain profit level. My goal is to effectively place a sell limit order, but to extend the upside if the stock continues to run. (Note: I did not include any down-side protection in this example)

**Will this work as described below?** (Platform: Think or Swim)

> Current stock price: 100
> Side: Sell
> Price rules: TRAILSTOPLIMIT
> Limit Price: 150
> Stop offset: -10

**Desired outcome:**
Will this place a trailing stop order of -10 if the stock prices goes up to 150?

Comment: Looks like you've got a correct answer below, but since you're on ToS you can do what you want by adding a condition to your trailing stop limit order (hit gear icon and under conditions enter symbol, choose mark, set trigger to >= and type in your threshold.) Then your trailing stop limit order will only take affect after the condition is met.

Comment: @HartCO Excellent. Thank you! Quick followup: I am trying to "buy to close" a short put option using the same conditional stop loss. The 'Symbol' under the 'Conditions' section automatically filled in the underlying (`WMT` in this case). Does the system know the trigger is actually based on the "WMT 100 (Weeklys)" or do I need to enter something else?

Comment: I'm only familiar with using stock price there, so if WMT hits x at any point then that condition is met and the order you entered gets placed. Just noticed 'affect' instead of 'effect' in my comment, oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the stop order will go into effect immediately. If the stock drops $10, the stop will be triggered, even if the stock did not reach $150 first. Since you don't want a stop to occur in that case, you may need a conditional order instead.

The role of the "limit price" in the "trailing stop limit" order appears to be that when the stop is triggered (upon a $10 drop), it becomes a limit order instead of a market order. So the sell order would have a limit price of $150.

The problem is that the order will execute if the stock drops $10 and *then* reaches at least $150, whereas you want it to execute if the stock reaches at least $150 and *then* drops $10.